# What is the default work group for windows

Tags: windows, networking, workgroup

MSHome? Or workgroup.

Sometimes I see mshome and sometimes I see workgroup.

What happen anyway if the workgroup changes? I can still see files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default workgroup after installation is `MSHOME` in Windows XP Home, but `WORKGROUP` in Windows XP Pro (and newer releases such as Vista).

If you access to a Windows share (or SAMBA server) via hostname, workgroup does not have an impact. However, if you use broadcast discovery (in simpler terms, if you navigate to *All Network* node in *Network* in Windows) hosts are grouped according to their workgroups. In this way you can put associated hosts into a single workgroup.